# Syntax error and is there a better way to write this?, with if - else conditional

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have just started learning Python, and I'm trying to self-learn it so I can test out of computer programming, to get to java, which is what I really want to learn. I know this isn't the easiest way to do this, but it's what I came up with. When I run it, there's a syntax error, but I don't really see it. I'm pretty sure I have a lot of things wrong with this.

Might someone help me with my syntax please?

Also, if someone could suggest some way to learn Python, or how they learnt it, because I might get a book on it or something.

> File "Triangletest.py", line 8 else tyy == 0
>               ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
T1 = input("First side of triangle:  ")
T2 = input("Second side of triangle:  ")
addi = T1 + T2
suub = T1 - T2
T3 = input("Third side of triangle:  ")
    tyy = 1
else tyy == 0
    if T3 < suub:
pss == 1
    else pss = 0
if tyy + pss == 2:
print("The triangle is not possible")
```

Comment: Hmm, there _are_ a lot of problems with this code -- enough that I can't really tell what you're trying to do. Don't be discouraged, though -- go online, look for some code examples, compare them to what you're doing here and see what might be wrong. Also check out http://www.diveintopython.net/ and http://learnpythonthehardway.org/.

Comment: Change tyy == 0  to tyy = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments:

```
T1 = input("First side of triangle:  ")
T2 = input("Second side of triangle:  ")
addi = T1 + T2
suub = T1 - T2
T3 = input("Third side of triangle:  ")
    tyy = 1 \ Identation does not work
else tyy == 0 # else requires a : at the end of the line and an if before it it never has a condition. use elif instead of else: if ...:
    if T3 < suub:
pss == 1 # you mus ident behind every :
    else pss = 0 # this is ok but : missing
if tyy + pss == 2: # there mus be something behind it.
```

Syntax ok:

```
T1 = input("First side of triangle:  ")
T2 = input("Second side of triangle:  ")
addi = T1 + T2
suub = T1 - T2
T3 = input("Third side of triangle:  ")
tyy = 1
if False: pass # if before else
elif tyy == 0:
    if T3 < suub:
        # should it be pss = 1 ?
        pss == 1 # this is in the if clause
    else: pss = 0
if tyy + pss == 2:
    pass # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to solve this: user enters sides, the program answers whether the triangle with those sides is possible. If you sort your sides, it will be much simpler.

```
sides = [float(input(ord + ' side of a triangle: '))
             for ord in 'First Second Third'.split()]
a, b, c = sorted(sides)
if c < a + b: print('Triangle is possible')
else: print('Triangle is impossible')
```